lots of untagged resources running in aws
I just tried running tag manager to list all resouces which are untagged in Tag Manager from all region. It started listing around 158 resources which are untagged.
.
It was mostly related to EC2.
Now my doubt is, what is this and do I delete all to save from billing or it is neccssary.

The resources you have shown are networking components that do not attract a charge.
For a list of chargeable VPC services, see: https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/
